# "Could not copy file" error preventing build in VB 2019

Tags: vb.net, build-error

I'm getting an error, "Could not copy the file [file name in app folder] because it was not found." This is giving me a build error, not a runtime error. There is no path or file given. I am using filecopy commands, but not even on the main form. I have searched the entire solution for "FileCopy," and the only 2 are in a form not yet loaded, within a try-catch-end try. How can I find the source of this error?

Comment: Try the following: On VS menu click Tools => Options... => Projects and Solutions => Build And Run. On right side, set both `MSBuild project build output verbosity` and `MSBuild project build log file verbosity` to `Diagnostic`.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks. But I'm not sure if the information it gave is anything close to a solution. the file name is  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Comment: The first thing to do is repair the VS2019 installation. If that doesn't help, googling for "Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" might lead you to a solution.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestions! Unfortunately they didn't seem to help. I did run a repair, in fact I did an update, and the error is still there. I changed the settings to Diagnostic, checked the line in the Target file (4999).  This is the copy command at line 4999, in a section labeled "Copy files that have the CopyToOutputDirectory attribute set to 'Always':

Comment: <Copy
        SourceFiles = "@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways)"
        DestinationFiles = "@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways->'$(OutDir)%(TargetPath)')"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
        Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
        RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"        UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible)"        UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="$(CreateSymbolicLinksForAdditionalFilesIfPossible)">
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </Copy>

Comment: @user3516774 If you create a new project, does that also have the problem?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I created a new blank project, and there was no similar problem. I suppose I could create a new project and copy everything into it, but that would be a substantial task.

Comment: @user9938, I did make the changes you suggested and found the code in the targets file. I posted it earlier. If that suggests a solution to you, please let me know.

Comment: @user3516774 If the build process has become corrupted, it might be less effort to copy everything to a new project than to find where it went wrong. If you were using version control (which you really should), you might be able to go back and find at what point it went wrong and investigate the changes to files which could have caused the problem. IMHO.

Comment: Try the following: Make a copy of your solution folder/files. Then in your solution folder delete `.vs` folder. In each project folder (within the solution), delete `bin` and `obj` folders. Open the solution. Then Build => Rebuild Solution.

Comment: Thanks @user3516774. I've already begun the tedious task of rebuilding the project from scratch. I just finished creating all the new forms (I tried to copy the form files over, but even after including resource files that was a mess), so now I'm ready to copy and paste the code. It has been a learning experience, to say the least.  This was an app that had grown kind of organically through several versions of VS, so it's probably time for this to happen anyway. Thanks again, folks.

Comment: @user9938, I've already started rebuilding the project. Thanks for the suggestion!